# 2 dimensional relative motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

I came across the following question:

> Airplanes A and B are flying with constant velocity in the same vertical plane at angles $30°$ and $60°$ as shown in the following figure. The speed of A is $100\sqrt{3}$ m/s. At time $t$=0, an observer in A finds B at a distance of 500 m. This observer sees B moving with a **constant velocity perpendicular to the line of motion of A**. If, at $t=t′$, A just escapes being hit by B, what is $t′$ (in s)?

[image: Picture of problem]

My question is this; when they say "moving with a constant velocity perpendicular to the line of motion of A", what do they mean? What information am I getting exactly? And also, how does A manage to escape being hit by B?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Relative motion.]

Imagine you're looking at the situation from *behind* plane $A$. For plane $B$ all you would see is the velocity perpendicular to the line of motion of $A$.

I've decomposed plane $B's$ velocity vector into a component **perpendicular** to $A$ and one **parallel** to $A$, using basic trigonometry. For the interception problem only the perpendicular component does the trick: the other component is simply parallel to $A$.

Comment: So what you're saying is that if I'm in plane A and look at plane B, I'd see it moving directly toward me in the perpendicular direction to my motion?

Comment: In a nutshell, yes.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much :) This should help me to proceed with the problem.

Comment: If the relative velocity of B with respect to A is purely perpendicular to the velocity of A, then this means that the parallel component of plane B's velocity is equal to the velocity of plane A, correct?

Comment: Otherwise, wouldn't the x and y components of the relative velocity of B with respect to A add up and give some other vector not perpendicular to A? Yes, I think this makes sense and that I've finally got the hang of it. Thanks so much, especially for the great diagram!

Comment: I'm going to *pass* on working out the full problem; it's very late here. Good night!

Comment: Oh, but I worked it out on my own, thanks to you! Good night!

Answer (score 1):

Write your position and velocity in vector form and solve this.

The information you get by that sentence is: *the **relative** velocity vector between A and B is perpendicular to the line of motion of A, or the direction vector of A's motion or the velocity vector of A.*

Giving out a slightly more informative equation,

$$(\vec{v_b}(t=0) -\vec{v_a}(t=0)).\vec{v_a}(t=0) = 0$$

Comment: Yes, OK, thanks :) Can u please give me a hint as to proceed with the problem? I don't understand how it is possible that A escapes being hit by B!

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar The position vector is $\vec{p} + \vec{v}t$, where $\vec{p}$ is position at $t=0$ and $\vec{v}$ is the velocity vector. If they intersect, then you should be able to solve for $t$, but if they don't, there will be no solution for $t$